Adjoint pairs induced on categories of presheaves by an adjoint pair
I don't understand what this exercise asks:

Let $F:C\leftrightarrows D:G$ be a pair of adjoint functors, with $F\dashv G$, between small categories. Let $(F_P,F^P)$ and $(G_P,G^P)$ be the adjunctions induced on the categories of presheaves: show that $F^P$ is naturally isomorphic to $G_P$.

I guess that $F_P:\hat D\to \hat C$ is the functor obtained by precomposition with $F$, and analogously $G_P:\hat C\to \hat D$. Both these functors have a left adjoint, respectively $F^P$ and $G^P$. However from the very little I read about this topic it seems that the left adjoint of $F_P$ is more complex than $G_P$, and is related to Kan extensions. The same problem occurs if we guess that $F^P$ and $G^P$ are the functor obtained by precomposition while $F_P$ and $G_P$ are their right adjoints.

I assume the functor $F^P : \widehat{D} \to \widehat{C}$ is precomposing with $F$, and $F_P : \widehat{C} \to \widehat{D}$ is its left adjoint.
For $X \in \widehat{C}$ and $d \in D$ we have the formula
$$F_P(X)(d) = \mathrm{colim}_{F(c) \to d} X(c),$$
which you can find for example in the chapter on Kan extensions in Mac Lane. Since $F$ is left adjoint to $G$, this can be written as
$$\mathrm{colim}_{c \to G(d)} X(c) = X(G(d)),$$
which proves $F_P = G^P$.

But in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/697646/presheaves-and-adjoint-functors you said that $G^P$ is continuous and $F_P$ in general is not; I don't understand where is the difference in the setting between that question and mine

Seems like I should fix that answer then.

I'm not sure if you're being sarcastic or not :( Do you confirm that $\alpha$, $\alpha_$ and $\alpha^$ of the question I linked are the same as $F$, $F^P$ and $F_P$ of my question, and analogously for $\beta $ and $G$? And that when you say: "$F_P$ cannot be of the form $G^P$ since $G^P$ is continuous but $F_P$ is usually not continuous" it is not true?

I wasn't sarcastic. But I will check again later today or tomorrow and adjust both answers in any case.

I have fixed the other answer. They are now saying basically the same. So it is a duplicate, actually.

Thank you! Since my question is a duplicate should I delete it or there is another procedure?
